# htaccess Rewrite for $_GET in PHP

Tags: php, url-rewriting

i currently have this in my htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ pages/$1.php
```

so when you go to the url `http://www.domain.com/services` it will go to the page `pages/services.php`

i want to be able to have

```
http://www.domain.com/services/service1
```

which will go to `pages/services.php?seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>`

How can I do this using htaccess Rewrite rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this rule before main one:

```
RewriteRule ^/{0,1}services/(service[0-9]+)/{0,1}$ pages/services.php?seq=$1  [NE,NC,L]
```

UPDATE:

if you need only numeric part of service### - use:

```
RewriteRule ^/{0,1}services/service([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ pages/services.php?seq=$1  [NE,NC,L]
```

note position of "("

Comment: (service[0-9]+) - what does the service do in this?

Comment: @charlie its just addition to clearly separate that this will work only for services with service after it and WILL NOT work for /abc/def1/ or /services/123/ or /services/qwe123/

Comment: hmm.. so if you go to www.domain.com/services/123 is will go to page www.domain.com/pages/services.php?seq=123

Comment: with current rule - no, it will go to 404 page (if there is no other rules)